# How to detect if HTML5 video can be played without user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Detecting if it is a touch device won't be accurate, think about touchscreen laptops.

Basically I want to be able to avoid displaying a video if it cannot start playing without user interaction.

For those thinking 'you are a bad person':

- The video will not have audio.
- It is a decorative asset in the page, it will be a background.
- I don't care about bandwidth, I am aiming towards the best user experience. Devices like phones won't have this video in it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What if you played a tiny transparent test video and monitored its progress? I'm also guessing this would be coupled with Modernizr.

http://modernizr.com/

```
function eventWindowLoaded() {

 var videoElement = document.getElementById("thevideo");

 videoElement.addEventListener('progress',makingProgress,false);
 videoElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough',playVideo,false);

}

function playVideo() {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById("thevideo");
    videoElement.play();
}

function makingProgress() {
    console.log("video can play");
}
```

Comment: Could be, I'm wondering if there is any way of knowing this without playing the video. If there is no other way, this will be the solution. Thanks

Comment: I've also used these other checks. Who knows, maybe they'll be useful to you at some point. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to either start playing and listen for the play event, or you need to check the user agent string for browsers that you know won't play, like Mobile Safari.

Since this is a deviation from the standard, the media API doesn't provide any specific way to detect this in advance, and modernizr probably can't help you. iOS is probably the biggest culprit here, so let's look at that. Until the latest version was released a few days ago, iOS wouldn't even load the video's metadata before there was a touch event. So you could detect it by setting the video to preload metadata and waiting for a timeout on the loadedmetadata event.

But in iOS 8, the API does load the metadata and will even fire canplaythrough and report that a large chunk of the video has been buffered. So it seems the only way to tell is to actually try and play.

(That said, I can't tell if the browser is really loading as much of the video as it says it is, since the network timeline in the developer tools doesn't show much, even after you start playing.)